# Synchronization problem with Jquery - not working without an alert

Tags: jquery, html, synchronization

I have a couple of buttons that when clicked, I changed their class using Jquery.
My problem is that its only works if I call an alert first.

I know this must be due to something that has not been loaded yet,
but I can't understand who and why.

This is my code:

```
     <input type="button" id="About" class="menu_button" value="About"/>
     <input type="button" id="Contact" class="menu_button" value="Contact" />

     <script>       

      $(".menu_button").click(function()
            {
                //alert("onMenuClick");
                $(".menu_button").removeClass("menu_button_selected");
                $(this).addClass("menu_button_selected");
            });


      </script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Pasted your code in jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/da7bV/1/ - and I don't see any problems with it. Does it work for you?

Comment: Yeah it workes in jsfiddle, but still not working on my site

Comment: Could there be something else that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: it is hard to know what's wrong with a working code...

Comment: I realized what went wrong - I had some javascript triggered onmouseout, that wasn't waiting for the element to be loaded

Answer (score 1):

<del>it is always a good thing to</del> You should always place your code inside an `onload` event

```
$(function() {
$(".menu_button").click(function()
            {
                //alert("onMenuClick");
                $(".menu_button").removeClass("menu_button_selected");
                $(this).addClass("menu_button_selected");
            });
});
```

The reason being that, some browsers will allow JS to execute even if the DOM tree is not yet fully loaded, and leading to elements not present, or not yet available. The jQuery function `$(function() { ... });` will ensure that the code inside will be run only when everything is loaded and ready.

** **UPDATE** **

Your `script` tags should look like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // js here
</script>
```

And [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Emj78/) is a test on jsfiddle showing that it works for the code you gave. If it does not work for you, then your problem is somewhere else. I suggest you use [Google Chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome/) and it's developper tool to debug your Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

This script work fine for me under Firefox :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {


 $(".menu_button").bind('click',function()
       {
           //alert("onMenuClick");
           $(".menu_button").removeClass("menu_button_selected");
           $(this).addClass("menu_button_selected");
       });
}
</script>
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me. only when I uncomment the alert

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your code in `$(function(){});` This means your code will only be executed when the DOM is ready for it:

```
<script>    

    $(function(){

        $(".menu_button").click(function()
        {
            //alert("onMenuClick");
            $(".menu_button").removeClass("menu_button_selected");
            $(this).addClass("menu_button_selected");
        });

    });

</script>
```

Comment: Are you sure that these classes are not being applied? They may be being applied but you can't see a difference in the css or styles. Have you tried (in Chrome or Safari) right clicking on the button and clicking "Inspect Element"? This will show you the element as it currently appears in the DOM.